# How can I exclude regex href matches of a particular domain?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I exclude href matches for a domain (ex. `one.com`)?

My current code:

```
$str = 'This string has <a href="http://one.com">one link</a> and <a href="http://two.com">another link</a>';
$str = preg_replace('~<a href="(https?://[^"]+)".*?>.*?</a>~', '$1', $str);
echo $str; // This string has http://one.com and http://two.com
```

Desired result:

```
This string has <a href="http://one.com">one link</a> and http://two.com
```

Comment: That'll work until you get `<a id="foo" href="....">`.  For reliability in the future, you'll want to look at DOMDocument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using a regular expression

If you're going to use a regular expression to accomplish this task, you can use a negative lookahead. It basically asserts that the part `//` in the `href` attribute is *not* followed by `one.com`. It's important to note that a lookaround assertion doesn't consume any characters.

Here's how the regular expression would look like:

```
<a href="(https?://(?!one\.com)[^"]+)".*?>.*?</a>
```

Regex Visualization:

[image]
[**Regex101 demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vW5jC8)

---

### Using a DOM parser

Even though this is a pretty simple task, the correct way to achieve this would be using a DOM parser. That way, you wouldn't have to change the regex if the format of your markup changes in future. The regex solution will break if the `<a>` node contains more attribute values. To fix all those issues, you can use a DOM parser such as PHP's DOMDocument to handle the parsing:

Here's how the solution would look like:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$dom->loadHTML($html); // $html is the string containing markup

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

//Loop through links and replace them with their anchor text
for ($i = $links->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $node = $links->item($i);

    $text = $node->textContent;
    $href = $node->getAttribute('href');

    if ($href !== 'http://one.com') {
        $newTextNode = $dom->createTextNode($text);
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newTextNode, $node);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[**Live Demo**](https://eval.in/147725)

Comment: @Ryan: Indeed, http://regex101.com is an invaluable tool for anyone dealing with regex. By the way, I added another solution using a DOM parser. See the edit.

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason you loop through in reverse? +1 for the `DOMDocument` solution I was too lazy to work on ;)

Comment: +1 for giving detailed explanation with both options, regex and Dom parser. Too often it becomes a religious war. I like your work. :)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://regex101.com/r/qP1zV9) should do it:

```
<a href="(https?://(?!one\.com)[^"]+)".*?>.*?</a>
```

We use a negative lookahead to make sure that `one.com` does not appear directly after the `https?://`.

---

If you also want to check for some subdomains of `one.com`, use [this example](http://regex101.com/r/dU8mS6):

```
<a href="(https?://(?!((www|example)\.)?one\.com)[^"]+)".*?>.*?</a>
```

Here we optionally check for `www.` or `example.` before `one.com`.  This will allow a URL like `misc.com`, though.  If you want to remove all subdomains of `one.com`, use [this](http://regex101.com/r/kU4pY2):

```
<a href="(https?://(?!([^.]+\.)?one\.com)[^"]+)".*?>.*?</a>
```

Comment: Yes, it just asserts to make sure that it doesn't ***begin*** with `one.com`.